# Vulcanize reusable elements in production

Tags: polymer, vulcanize

I have a custom element (my-element), and this folder structure:

```
my-element
├── bower_components
│   ├── paper-menu
│   ├── paper-checkbox
├── my-element.html
```

My element uses the above two paper-elements, but it imports them by the canonical path:

```
<link rel="import" href="../paper-menu/paper-menu.html">
```

instead of

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-menu/paper-menu.html">
```

This is possible by using polyserve, as described by Rob Dodson in [Create reusable elements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p7Q1mQtFGM8&t=20s), or by using a custom gulp configuration as I did.

How can I vulcanize in this case `my-element.html` ?

Vulcanize obviously cannot detect the canonical path, so I've tried several things, including vulcanize options and gulp tricks (like a gulp-replace pipe), but no success yet. Thank you!